# Wordpress MySQL wp_post export/ import

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to export an old wp_posts database into a new one, and I'm hitting a few brick walls.

I'm currently exporting in SQL compatibility mode: MYSQL40.

Here's the error:

````
--
-- Database: `grafiqe`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_actionscheduler_actions`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_actionscheduler_actions` (
  `action_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hook` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `scheduled_date_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `scheduled_date_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `args` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `schedule` longtext,
  `group_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_attempt_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_attempt_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `claim_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `extended_args` varchar(8000) DEFAULT NULL
)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1050 - Table 'wp_actionscheduler_actions' already exists```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet already tells you the error

````
#1050 - Table 'wp_actionscheduler_actions' already exists```
````

It's not possible to create a table with the name of a table that already exists in the database. Daft question, but are you importing it into the new empty database and not the same one you just exported it from?